# Jquery Toggle events not called

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I am trying to toggle a div with jquery to show hide child items. I am trying to add class to parent item on toggle open event and close event. How can we track toggle events?
[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ayk/1/)

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
     $("#panel").toggle();
 });

$("#panel").toggle(
  function() {
    alert("first event");
  }, function() {
    alert("second event");
  });
```

Comment: there is no toggle event - slideToggle() toggles the display that is all - it doesn't fire any event

Comment: Sorry, It is slideToggle which is almost similar to toggle.

Comment: SlideToggle takes one function, not two.

Comment: Could you please make it with Toggle. Sorry for the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `complete` callback when calling [**`slideToggle()`**](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) inside which you can determine whether your element was slid up or down.

```
$("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle(function() {
        if($(this).is(':visible')) {
            alert('Panel is visible');
            // code to add class. "this" refers to the panel here
        }
        else {
            alert('Panel is not visible');
            // code to remove class. "this" refers to the panel here
        }
    });
});
```

Updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r3ayk/2/)**